# Search and Delete / Regex / Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a input where the User can enter his Code. The `text_area` input would look something like this

```
// ==UserScript== // @name test.org Scam Filter // @description Filters out scam scripts at Userscripts.org. // @namespace http://test.org:8080/scripts/review/163038 // @icon http://s3.test.com/uso_ss/icon/163038/large.png?1365299642 // @updateURL https://test.com/89.meta.js?c // @downloadURL https://test.com/89.user.js?c // @homepageURL https://test.com/code.php?id=89 // @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js // @include http*://test.org:8080/ // @include http*://test.org:8080/scripts* // @include http*://test.org:8080/tags/* // @grant GM_getValue // @grant GM_setValue // @grant GM_listValues // @version 5.33 // ==/UserScript== $(document).ready(function(){ // Load jQuery cookie functions and viewport visibility selectors loadJQcookies(); loadJQViewport(); /* The following 5 arrays comprise the blacklist.  etc etc etc
```

What i need is to delete from `// ==UserScript==` till `// ==/UserScript==`, but can't seem to find it.

for finding that specific code_block i use this regular expression:

```
source.scan( /\A\/\/\s==UserScript==(\w|\W)*\/\/\s==\/UserScript==$/ )
```

But i can't find a way to delete it..

I'm trying to run this in my model as a `def delete_block` and call `before_create` on it..

I tried

```
self.source.gsub(/\A\/\/\s==UserScript==(\w|\W)*\/\/\s==\/UserScript==$/, '' )
```

But i think i'm missing the logic here.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is with the `$` in the end. `$` denotes "end of string". Since you string does not end with `UserScript==`, the match fails, and you find nothing:

```
self.source.gsub(/\A\/\/\s==UserScript==(\w|\W)*\/\/\s==\/UserScript==/, '' )
self.source
# => " $(document).ready(function(){ // Load jQuery cookie functions and viewport visibility selectors loadJQcookies(); loadJQViewport(); /* The following 5 arrays comprise the blacklist.  etc etc etc"
```

Comment: Hey Uri, thanks for pointing that out.. Indeed in my Console it is working now. But on my Application things get messy.. I think it has to do that i use redcarpet for markdown ?!.. Is there a way for me to actually process this before everything else ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking - what happens? why do you think it is related to redcarpet? is there an error? what is it?

Comment: I don't really know if it's redcarpet, i'm just Guessing. On App it doesn't work and i have absolutely no idea why.. No errors, Just goes on an the code is still there. Can i give you more information about something specific? Maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: No it's not Redcarpet, i tested it on an blank input.. Still the same :/

Comment: I restarted the Server and it Worked.. i have NO idea why :) Anyways Thanks uri